# Create a list of repeated values and edit it with loop

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list with **n** elements. All elements are the same. Then I need to change the values using *for loop*. Here's my code:

```
n = 4
array = [[0, False]] * n

print(array)

count = 1
for a in array:
    if a[0] == 0:
        a[0] = count
        a[1] = True
        count += 1

print(array)
```

The result I get is:

```
[[0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False]] 
[[1, True], [1, True], [1, True], [1, True]]
```

But I expected to get:

```
[[0, False], [0, False], [0, False], [0, False]]
[[1, True], [2, True], [3, True], [3, True]]
```

And why does the line `a = [count, True]` not change the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have a copy of the same underlying list.

Try something like:

```
array = [[0, False] for i in range(n)]
```

There is probably a better way, the idea is to create a new list for each entry.

Comment: thank you!! and could you please explain why I can't use `a = [count, True]` to edit an element of array?

Comment: You can, bu if you use `array = [[0, False]] * n`, then you create a list of size `n`, but the elements you put in are the same list referenced `n` times instead of new lists. If after you change one entry in the list and replace with another list, of course, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
n = 4
array = [[0, False]] * n

print(array)

newarray = []
for a in array:
    a[0] += 1
    a[1] = True
    new = [str(a[0]) + '' ,'' + str(a[1])]
    newarray.append(new)
    for b in newarray:
        b[0] = int(b[0])
        b[1] = bool(a[1])

print(newarray)
```